# Spring maven project build is failing due to test resources not found

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, tomcat

Maven build is failing, and the reason behind it is test files not found from test/resources folder.

src/test/java and src/test/resources folders are added in java build path src folder and in deployment assembly also.

Could it be due to any incompatibility with maven 3.3.3 and eclipse 2020-03, is there any required configuration missing here?

Comment: Is that the first error you get? I'd expect it to be the last of a long series of errors (probably started by an exception thrown by Spring's `WebApplicationInitializer`) that cause an unscheduled Tomcat shutdown.

Comment: The problem I found now is my build is not successfully made. While making build it's complaining about junits failing due to test/resource file not found.
I have given folder test/resources in Java build path and Deployment Assembly as well.

Comment: So is this question still the question?